# Making a PostgreSQL query with variable filters faster

Tags: sql, postgresql, query-optimization, postgresql-performance

So I have the following query:

```
WITH temp_table as (
  SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY id ASC) AS rownum 
  FROM table 
  WHERE name = ? 
    AND bool_value != True 
  ORDER BY ?
) 
SELECT * 
FROM temp_table 
WHERE column1 = ? 
 and column2 = ? 
 and column3 = ?
```

This query usually returns around 100k+ rows but it takes around 20 seconds to complete. I would like to minimise this time. The name will be different depending on the user that is executing the query. The `'WHERE column1 = ? and column2 = ? and column3 = ?'` part will differ depending on what the user wants to check for; the use may not even request for any filters:

```
SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY id ASC) AS rownum 
FROM table 
WHERE name = ? 
AND bool_value != True 
ORDER BY ?
```

The user may also order the data by different values.

I have tried indexing but couldn't figure out a correct index to make this query faster. There is also another query that is extremely slow:

```
SELECT * 
FROM table 
WHERE bool_value = True 
WHERE column1 = ? 
  and column2 = ?
 and column 3 = ?
ORDER BY ?
```

This query can return up to 60k rows in the user doesn't enter in any filters but it takes around 10-20 seconds to complete.

Comment: Please **[edit]** your question and add the [execution plan](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/using-explain.html) generated using `explain (analyze, buffers, format text) select ... ` (**not** just a "simple" explain) as  [formatted text](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) and make sure you preserve the indention of the plan. Paste the text, then put `\`\`\`` on the line before the plan and on a line after the plan. Ideally for all three variants, but at least for the first query.

Comment: It's the columns mentioned in your queries' WHERE clauses that you will use to determine what columns should go into your indexes. But you've told us you don't know which columns are involved until your user tells you. With respect, that makes it very difficult to help you.

Comment: So you positively ***need*** the row number from *before* possible filters on `column1`,`column2`, `column3`? That forces Postgres to walk through all candidate rows and is guaranteed to be slow (unless you can materialize the row number for read-only data).

Comment: Also, the PostgreSQL version is relevant.

Answer (score 0):

First, the `order by` in the CTE is not helpful (Postgres is not guaranteed to follow it), I would recommend writing the CTE as:

```
SELECT t.*, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY id ASC) AS rownum 
FROM table t
WHERE t.name = ? AND bool_value = False ;
```

Note:  This assumes that `bool_value` is not ever `NULL`.

Then, for this query, you want an index on: `(name, bool_value, id)`.

I don't think there is much that you can do about the outer query.